# Swift: Private Constants vs Constant Type Properties

Tags: swift, constants, private, class-properties

Should I use a constant type property instead of a private constant?

At the top of my `ChatViewController.swift` file, outside of the class definition, I have a private constant:

```
private let messageFontSize: CGFloat = 17
```

But since this constant is only used by instances of `ChatViewController`, should I move it inside of the class definition and make it a constant type property?

```
class ChatViewController: UIViewController {
    static let messageFontSize: CGFloat = 17
    // . . .
}
```

But then, I'd have to access it rather verbosely:

```
ChatViewController.messageFontSize
```

Answer (score 1):

I would move it into the class regardless whether it is used somewhere else or not. There is always one class that sort of "owns" a constant. If the class makes it available to other classes then make it public (Well, in swift default would do in most cases). And yes, consequentally you will have to prefix it with the class' name.